# Problems running graphical applications as root

Tags: graphics, root

If I try to run firefox (`$ firefox`) or xxdiff (`$ xxdiff`) through my user, everything works as it should, but once I log in as root (`su -`), errors occur:

```
# firefox
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified

# xxdiff
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (stack dumped)
```

Hope anyone has encountered or knows how to solve the problem.
Trying to change DISPLAY didn't succeed, but maybe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Just don't run then as root. There is no use case when you need it.

Comment: Listen to @Pilot6 don't run apps as root.

Comment: firefox I don't really need from root, but for example xxdiff can come in handy when diff can't give the desired result (for example, when many consecutive lines are different)